# Button isnt greyed out when disabled

Tags: python, wxpython

I have one button and when user clicks it I catch an event and in the handler function I call Disable() function on that button but it isnt greyed out... Only if I click on some other widget after that, button becomes greyed out... Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds strange. Try one of these...

- Use `wx.CallAfter(button.Disable)` instead of `button.Disable()`.
- Call `button.Refresh()` after disabling it.